# Including tex file in rmd

Tags: latex, r-markdown

This is literally my first day working with latex and rmd, both. This might be the silliest of questions, but I want to know how to include a latex file in my rmd. 
I did something like:

```
---
title: "TITLE"
output: pdf_document:
includes: myLatex.tex
---
```

But I'm getting the below error:

*Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2, column 21
Calls:  ... yaml_load_utf8 -> mark_utf8 ->  -> .Call
Execution halted*

Comment: Try adding two spaces in front of `includes:`.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that in some cases YAML in R Markdown appears to take issue with multiple colons in the same line. In your case, this may be occurring at `output: pdf_document:`. Try dropping that down a level, like so:

```
---
title: "TITLE"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes: myLatex.tex
---
```